# Is it possible to use one parameter in another in AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

**Current setup:**

There's a master data source that contains attendance records per day for students in a given school.  Imagine the data is structured in a CSV format like so:

name|day|in_attendance

jack|01/01/2018|0

and so on and so forth, throughout the entire year.  Now, the way we grab attendance information from a specific period in time is to specify the year & month via parameters we're handing to an AWS Datapipeline Step, like so:

`myAttendanceLookupStep: PYTHON=python34,s3://school_attendance_lookup.py,01,2018`

that step runs the Python file defined, and `01` and `2018` specify month and year we're looking up.  However, I want to change it so that it looks more like this:

`myAttendanceLookupStep: PYTHON=python34,s3://school_attendance_lookup.py,%myYear,%myMonth
myYear: 2018
myMonth: 01`

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behavior in AWS Data Pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the syntax I was using in the example wasn't far from the proper syntax.  You can use supplied parameters in any portion of the pipeline (activities, etc.) - you do `#{myParameterName}` in place of where the parameter would go.

This doesn't appear to be documented in AWS Data Pipeline documentation.